# Vuejs3 combine computed field together

Tags: vuejs3

I'm trying to reuse a computed field in Vue3 :

```
export default {
  props: ["value", "target"],
  data() {
    return {
      visible: false,
      value: 25,
      target: 100,
      colored: "green",
      achieve:0,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    achieve: function () {
      return parseFloat(((this.value / this.target) * 100).toFixed(2));
    },
    colored: function(){
        if (achieve > 95){
            colored="green";
          } else if (achieve>85){
            colored="yellow";
          } else {colored="red";}
    }
  },
};
```

Console says achieve is not defined. How can I re-use this computed value in another computed value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code here.

First things first, you shouldn't have same name for data properties and computed properties because your computed properties will be ignored and you will have a warning in the console.

In this case you need the data properties at all, it should be like this:

```
  data() {
    return {
      visible: false,
      value: 25,
      target: 100,
    };
  },
```

Second problem would be that your computed property doesn't return a value.
Your colored computed property should look like this:

```
    colored: function(){
        if (this.achieve > 95){
            return "green";
          } else if (this.achieve > 85){
            return "yellow";
          } else {
            return "red";
        }
    }
```

Since you are accessing achieve computed property in your colored computed property you need to use `this.` when accessing it and that is why you are getting `achieve is not defined` error in the console.